# Using VBA to email a file without using outlook

Tags: vba

If outlook is not installed on a computer, is there anyway of using another mail client to send emails eg "Windows live 2012", "Thunderbird" or another?

If outlook is needed, then is there a free version that can be used ( can it be used on windows 10 and 7?)

Also related, is that when I use word on window 10, the default windows 10 mail client will not let me mail merge from word to an email.  I installed Windows live 2012 to get around this.   I though this was a bit rubbish that windows 10 behaved in this way by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use an SMTP (Simple Mail Transfer Protocol) Server.  Luckily Gmail is set up to do this easily.  There is a tutorial here that will walk you through step-by-step.  I have used this method many times and it works very well.

[VBA Email with Gmail](http://www.blueclaw-db.com/access_email_gmail.htm)

Edit to add link on File Attachment:

[File Attachment using CDO](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2004/11/29/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-an-email-sent-using-cdo.aspx)